# cairo-dock has problem with lubuntu

Tags: graphics, lubuntu, desktop-environments, cairo-dock

cairo-dock visual performance is poor in lubuntu.  My desktop suffers with black background when I navigate my mouse pointer on Cairo dock.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: You need to turn on the composite.
It's handled by your Window Manager (metacity, compiz, xfwm, etc)

Comment: Although fabounet is correct about compisiting, if your running lubuntu in the first place you are likely to be speed/memory constrained. Have you looked at AWN ? It's really light.

Comment: there is also a Cairo Dock setting: System > Composition > "emulate composition with fake transparency" that might work, depending on your system/version.  @fabounet would know better than I would though.

Answer (score 2):

Use a seperate lightweight compositor: `xcompmgr` 
(or use a heavyweight like compiz)

**Install:**

```
sudo apt-get install xcompmgr
```

**Run it just once (until you logout):**

```
xcompmgr -n
```

Or have it started automatically by adding it in the systemwide startup:

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

Or create a desktop icon for it and add this to your desktop session startup:

```
~/.config/autostart
```

(last option makes it very easy to turn it on or off via Desktop Session Settings )